# Is there a different way to automatically adjust the length of a jupyter list?

Tags: python, jupyter

I am using for loops to shorten my code for grabbing specific sections of a dataframe and finding the mean and standard deviation. I am then saving those values into a list, since there are different data types.

I wanted to simply initializing the list by writing `list=[0,0,0]*(len(cities))` to automatically create an x by 3 list, where x is however many cities there are. The problem with this, as shown in the picture, is that setting a single index to a value, such as `list[0][1]=1`, doesn't only affect that index, but instead affects every 3rd column in every row.

I was hoping for a more elegant solution than simply manually counting the number of cities and copy/pasting [0,0,0],.... that many times. I realize a solution is not to use for loops as I did and avoid lists altogether, but that's not the point for this question.

[Simple image of the issue described above. Value being applied to all rows of list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzO9X.png)

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/hruFz.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzO9X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zeros = [[0,0,0] for _ in range(50)]
```

is one way

but probably better to do

```
zeros = numpy.zeros((50,3))
```

(if a numpy.array will suffice)

if you have mixed datatypes you will need to use (e.g. strings and numbers)

```
zeros = numpy.zeros((50,3),object)
```

Comment: I tried that at first, but some entries are strings, and the np arrays didn't like that. From what I've read, np arrays can only have one type of data type, and I have float64 and strings.

Comment: I edited my post to address that  (note the first answer would work fine in any case... its just less efficient usually)

Comment: Awesome, yes that last bit did what I needed. Maybe I missed the "object" when reading the documentation, or it just wasn't there.